# Value of functions with restricted range.

Tags: functions

Let's say I define a function $f(x)=x$ and I specify that the range of this function is $\{1\}$. Then what would be the value of $f(3)$ for example? I would say that it is undefined. But then that suggests that there is more to evaluating a function than just using the formula and plugging in the values. Is part of evaluating a function checking that the value it is being evaluated at is in the domain and that the the result of that function at that value is in the range? That is, what has to be shown to prove that $f(1)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

It's a trifle unclear what you're asking. Recall what the three aspects of a function are: the domain (the allowed input values), the range (the output values coming from input values in the domain), and the rule of association (how input values get mapped to output values). So, the way you've worded the problem, it's a bit unclear what your domain is. Are you specifying it? Or are you specifying rules that the domain must follow? Most of the time, you don't restrict the range: the domain plus the rule of association completely determines the range.

At face value, the statement $f(x)=x$ and setting the range is equal to the singleton set $\{1\}$ restricts the domain artificially to $\{1\},$ so that even writing $f(3)$ is nonsense.

You should always check that function evaluation is happening in the domain. However, as mentioned above, since the range is determined from the domain and the rule of association, you don't usually need to check if the result is in the range - that's usually automatic.

To prove that $f(1)=1$ in your case is rather trivial: $1$ is in the domain, and the rule of association does the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. A function has a domain and it does not make sense to ask for its value at some point outside of it. The domain is part of the function. In particular you cannot find the domain of a function all you can do is attach a domain to a given expression to construct a function.